# Why no fluid from bleeder valve

Tags: honda, cooling-system

My car is overheating. I have new water pump, thermostat, radiator, radiator cap and timing belt.

When the bleeder valve is opened nothing comes out of it.

Does anyone have any idea what the issue could be?

Comment: Could you provide any additional information please?  What have you tried?  Do you have a photo of the bleeder valve so we know exactly what you are talking about?  Also, could you please provide the make/model/year of the car.  1982 Civics are a lot different from 2013 Ridgelines.  Thanks and welcome to the site!  Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

1. Bleeder valve or orifice in housing is clogged
2. Coolant is real low.

Comment: Check #2 first, then pull the bleeder valve out and confirm that you have a clear passage to the cooling system. Pulling the valve will let the system bleed.